# I am trying to to put 5 boxplot graphs in R. Each of them come out really squished. How do I fix this?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to to put 5 boxplot graphs in R. Each of them come out really squished. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Other than the `par(mar=...)` answer below, if you are expecting much help I suggest you provide reproducible code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass different margins `mar` to `par`.

http://rfunction.com/archives/1302